Is there a way to use Envelope creation by template and EmbeddedSignature?
We will have an web application which will generate contracts to be signed. And since it's possible to create templates on DocuSign environment we were asked if the following flow is possible.
Person fill our data in our application;
.... Business logic to validate that data ....
After validated we embbed a docusign environment to sign the document already filled with data. This without craeting a pdf document previously.
I'm trying to study their documentation, but their flow isn't clear enough to me on the parts after the envelope creation.
Can I use the information returned to send to my app embbed that?
{ "envelopeId": "eead435f-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-25b7d8523d2b", "uri": "/envelopes/eead435f-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-25b7d8523d2b", "statusDateTime": "2020-08-18T23:36:26.8830000Z", "status": "sent" }

Recommend you use what we call Composite Template which will give you more flexibly later for any changes in requirements or design.
This is the how-to article to show how to do this.
Here is the JSON for this:
{
    "compositeTemplates": [
        {
            "compositeTemplateId": "1",
            "inlineTemplates": [
                {
                    "recipients": {
                        "carbonCopies": [
                            {
                                "email": "'"${CC_EMAIL}"'",
                                "name": "'"${CC_NAME}"'",
                                "recipientId": "2",
                                "roleName": "cc"
                            }
                        ],
                        "signers": [
                            {
                                "clientUserId": "1000",
                                "email": "'"${SIGNER_EMAIL}"'",
                                "name": "'"${SIGNER_NAME}"'",
                                "recipientId": "1",
                                "roleName": "signer"
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    "sequence": "2"
                }
            ],
            "serverTemplates": [
                {
                    "sequence": "1",
                    "templateId": "' > $request_data
                    printf "${template_id}" >> $request_data
                    printf '"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "compositeTemplateId": "2",
            "document": {
                "documentBase64": "' >> $request_data
                cat $doc1_base64 >> $request_data
                printf '",
                "documentId": "1",
                "fileExtension": "html",
                "name": "Appendix 1--Sales order"
            },
            "inlineTemplates": [
                {
                    "recipients": {
                        "carbonCopies": [
                            {
                                "email": "'${CC_EMAIL}'",
                                "name": "'"${CC_NAME}"'",
                                "recipientId": "2",
                                "roleName": "cc"
                            }
                        ],
                        "signers": [
                            {
                                "email": "'"${SIGNER_EMAIL}"'",
                                "name": "'"${SIGNER_NAME}"'",
                                "recipientId": "1",
                                "roleName": "signer",
                                "tabs": {
                                    "signHereTabs": [
                                        {
                                            "anchorString": "**signature_1**",
                                            "anchorUnits": "pixels",
                                            "anchorXOffset": "20",
                                            "anchorYOffset": "10"
                                        }
                                    ]
                                }
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    "sequence": "1"
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "status": "sent"
}

